# Listviews text-font

Tags: android, colors, android-listview

I have a issue with my listview, I basicly want the text in the fields (in the listview) to become black instead of white as default. I've followed a simple guide how manage this but it is not working for me. This is the guide: http://www.hascode.com/2011/12/writing-styles-and-themes-on-android/ .

This is my style.xml file were I try to enter a dark color to the text:

```
<style name="CustomTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

This is my bookmarks.xml were I try to load the style in the listview with following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/CustomTextView">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've also tried to change the parent name in the style.xml to TextAppearance.Medium instead, but nothing works. Am I missing smomething, why can´t I just change the damn color? Please help! Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView is a kind of container... Inside list view you add the views.. in your case you are adding TextViews... so you should set the style of that TextView which you are adding to this ListView...

Answer (score 2):

you should set the `style="@style/CustomTextView"` to the UI element that represent your listview's row (the TextView where you will put the text, eg)

Comment: I understand what you mean. The problem is if you follow his guide, he has not created any UI element (textview) where you can manage to set the textcolor? So I do not understand how he can change it. Shall I create a new TextView in my bookmarks.xml file were the listview is placed? What I am trying to say is, I have no idea were the current UI element (textview) for the listview is placed since I have not implemented it myself....

Comment: add in res/layout a new xml file contains a textview. assign an id to this textview and pass it to the adapter.